# How can I find out what version of TLS my Restify Node app is using?

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, restify

I have a node app using a restify client. It talks to a server via HTTPS. How can I find out what version of TLS it is using to talk to a server?

My JSON client: `const jsonClient = restifyClients.createJsonClient(jsonClientConfig);`

`node -v` outputs `v8.9.1`

In my `package.json` I have `"restify-clients": "1.5.2"`